# How to open a URL that contains an ampersand & with start command?

Tags: batch-file, url, browser, cmd

I already know that to open a webpage with the default browser you use:
`start www.google.com`. However, I'm trying to open a URL that contains a '&' in it for example:

```
https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world
```

If I use:

```
start https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world
```

It will not work because there is a `&`

Comment: Have you tried to quote (`"http://...."`) the URL?

Answer (score 18):

`&` is a special character in bash, so if the URL contains a special character you just have to do it like this:

```
start "" "your url"
```

Comment: This worked for me. Note that this will open the URL with whatever application is configured as the default browser.

Answer (score 10):

You have to escape the Ampersand (&) character with the ^ character in every occurrence of it.

```
start https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl^&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off^&q=hello+world
```

Answer (score 5):

## Powershell

By passing through powershell : `powershell Start-Process <browser> <URL>`.

If you don't specify browser, then URL is open in your default browser. Mine is Google Chrome, so i have added `chrome`. For internet explorer, it will be `iexplorer` and for Mozilla Firefox, this is `firefox`.

Examples from a CMD prompt :

```
powershell Start-Process chrome http://google.com/
```

or a little bit shorter :

```
powershell Start-Process http://google.com/
```

or even more shorter :

```
powershell start http://google.com
```

However, in your case, type in the one hand `powershell` command to goto powershell prompt. In the other hand, just type one of the following command line by specifying URL with `""` in order to dodge the `&` effect as explained by jgmh above :

```
start "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

or by chosing a specific browser such as `firefox` :

```
start firefox "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

or else :

```
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("firefox.exe","https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world")
```

Finally, type `exit` in order to quit the powershell prompt.

## CMD

---

### Using start command only

idris19's method is really handy !

This command line can also help you because you are able to indicate your browser : `start <browser> <URL>`.

As said before, URL is open in your default browser if none is specified.

For instance :

```
start http://google.com
```

or

```
start chrome http://google.com
```

But, in your case, don't forget to add `""` to avoid `&` issue **and** mention your browser to not run URL in another cmd window :

```
start chrome "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

You can add `-incognito` flag to goto an incognito browser if necessary :

```
start chrome "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world" -incognito
```

---

### Using windows explorer

Furthermore, you can use windows explorer as following : `explorer <URL>`.
It **always** will open your URL in the default browser.

Example :

```
explorer http://google.com
```

As previously mentioned, don't forget the double quotes in your case due to `&` special character :

```
explorer "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

**Note** : Tested on Windows 10 64bits.

*P.S : Please, don't hesitate to edit my answer because i probably made grammatical mistakes due to my low english level. Thanks !
Best regards :-)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL shorteners.

For your link:

```
start [created link]
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable solution.  There's no need for a URL shortener.

Answer (score 1):

First provide the full path to the browser application file and then the complete link like this:

```
start "C:\Path\To\Browser.exe" "http://WebsiteURL.com"
```

Comment: This isn't ideal.  You should use whatever browser the user wants to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Linux you can try using these command

```
$links http://google.com
```

or

```
$elinks http://google.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these command lines:

```
powershell -command "start 'https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world'"
```

or

```
start "" "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

or even this one:

```
explorer "https://www.google.dz/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world"
```

Answer (score -1):

When I tried the same, it worked for me only by typing :

```
C:\start https://www.google.dz/?ws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=rXc_WYq3Msy2abGXpugH#safe=off&q=hello+world
```

in the Command Prompt.

Comment: This will not work as you should not need to type C:\ at the start of the command, the command should start with the word 'start'. This would look for a file called 'start' in the root of C:

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `start chrome -u url here`.

Comment: That won't work for the **default** browser